# Не все UDP пакеты читаются, что делаю не так?

Tags: python, udp

Есть код вида:

```
udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM,socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
udp_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0",67))

while True:
    data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    if gconfig["debug"]==True:print (addr)
```

Проблема в том, что tcpdump я вижу что UDP пакеты идут, Но! на экран выводятся не все пакеты..

```
root@cryos:~ # tcpdump -i igb1.104 port 67
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on igb1.104, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:16:46.847360 IP 172.30.114.79.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:e3:cf:b7 (oui Unknown), length 548
13:16:46.878704 IP 172.30.116.143.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c8:3a:35:0d:42:60 (oui Unknown), length 306
13:16:49.848217 IP 172.30.114.79.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:e3:cf:b7 (oui Unknown), length 548
13:16:50.870883 IP 172.30.116.131.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.871018 IP 172.30.116.88.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.871059 IP 172.30.116.90.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.871081 IP 172.30.120.132.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.871893 IP 172.30.114.98.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.871912 IP 172.30.114.101.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.872273 IP 172.30.116.194.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.873758 IP 172.30.116.111.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.876344 IP 172.30.116.195.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:50.884436 IP 172.30.116.146.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:9c:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.940398 IP 172.30.114.193.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.941983 IP 172.30.116.172.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.942011 IP 172.30.116.182.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.942088 IP 172.30.116.177.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.942103 IP 172.30.116.179.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.942117 IP 172.30.116.169.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.942368 IP 172.30.116.147.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.942400 IP 172.30.116.178.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.943002 IP 172.30.116.176.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:51.945750 IP 172.30.116.192.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 70:72:cf:5e:97:20 (oui Unknown), length 300
13:16:52.241558 IP 172.30.116.81.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:72:42:97 (oui Unknown), length 311
13:16:52.463263 IP 172.30.114.50.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c0:25:e9:e7:cd:01 (oui Unknown), length 311
13:16:52.857756 IP 172.30.114.79.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:e3:cf:b7 (oui Unknown), length 548
13:16:54.484766 IP 172.30.116.81.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:72:42:97 (oui Unknown), length 311
13:16:57.484738 IP 172.30.116.81.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:72:42:97 (oui Unknown), length 311
13:16:57.847048 IP 172.30.114.79.bootpc > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:e3:cf:b7 (oui Unknown), length 548
```

Вывод скрипта:

```
('172.30.114.79', 68)
('172.30.114.79', 68)
('172.30.120.132', 67)
('172.30.114.98', 68)
('172.30.114.101', 68)
('172.30.114.193', 68)
('172.30.114.50', 68)
('172.30.114.79', 68)
```

Например нет пакета от 172.30.116.81
Более подробный вывод пакета от 172.30.116.81:

```
tcpdump: listening on igb1.104, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:43:32.375086 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 504, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 339)
    172.30.116.81.bootps > 172.30.114.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d4:6e:0e:72:42:97 (oui Unknown), length 311, hops 1, xid 0x4857782e, Flags [none]
      Gateway-IP 172.30.116.81
      Client-Ethernet-Address d4:6e:0e:72:42:97 (oui Unknown)
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
        MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1024
        Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether d4:6e:0e:72:42:97
        Hostname Option 12, length 9: "TL-WR840N"
        Vendor-Class Option 60, length 8: "MSFT 5.0"
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 11: 
          Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server, Domain-Name
          Vendor-Option, Netbios-Name-Server, Netbios-Node, Netbios-Scope
          Static-Route, Classless-Static-Route, Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft
        Agent-Information Option 82, length 18: 
          Circuit-ID SubOption 1, length 8: ^@^F^@^A^A^@^@^C
          Remote-ID SubOption 2, length 6: M-xM-pM-^B^PM-zM-$
```

Comment: На какой машине находится ip 172.30.114.1 на той же, где запущен ваш скрипт ?

Comment: Да, всё на одной

Comment: mac-адрес назначения бы в выводе tcpdump увидеть. до приложения пакет, показанный tcpdump, может не дойти в двух случаях: mac-адрес назначения не вашей машины (tcpdump смотрит все пролетающие мимо пакеты, не только предназначенные вашей машине), или если пакет был зарублен фаерволом (см. iptables, в первую очередь цепочку INPUT)

Comment: Мне как раз слушать нужно ВСЕ пролетающие мимо пакеты в том числе... Может флажки какие нужно поставить udp_socket.setsockopt(... дополнительные?

Comment: Если смотреть по MAC назначения, то он есть в списке интерфейсов:root@cryos:~ # ifconfig | grep "90:e2:ba:57:f9:af"
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 hwaddr 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af
 ether 90:e2:ba:57:f9:af

Comment: Если все пролетающие мимо, то во первых придется использовать raw socket (например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python) во вторых может потребоваться перевод карты в promiscous режим (если они вдруг все таки по mac не пролазят)

Comment: Правда тогда странно почему часть вы все таки видите. если бы они были именно "мимо пролетающие", то вы бы никакие не видели. гляньте файрвол. других предположений не осталось

Comment: Да, проблема таки оказалась в файреволе. Однако странно, что другие приложения (например стандартный DHCP сервер), вполне эти пакеты тоже видел. Как они обходят файревол?

Comment: dhcp серверу приходится читать и не совсем стандартные ip пакеты, когда еще нет ip адресов (первый запрос). а для этого ему приходится использовать raw socket. А раз raw уже используется он им читает все. А пакеты на raw попадают до фаервола